# Evento hover que funciona que funciona en javascript y no en css

Tags: javascript, css, css3

Tengo un `div` con una imagen de fondo, adentro de ese `div` tengo 
un `div` con `position:absolute`.

Lo que quiero hacer es que cuando pase el `mouse` por el `div` contenedor se pinte el borde del `div` que esta adentro en blanco, hasta ahí todo perfecto.

Pero luego quiero que cuando se pase `mouse` por el `div` que esta adentro, el borde de este se pinte de otro color.

Pero no  puedo lograr eso, al menos con `CSS`. Lo intente con `Javascript` y si se puede, pero prefiero evitar el uso se `Javascript` para esto.

Alguien que me pueda decir: ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

Este es mi codigo:

```css
.figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 15.1%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 3.9%;
  right: 3.9%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}

.circulo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  border: solid 8px transparent;
}

.figure:hover .circulo {
  border: 8px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.6);
}

.circulo:hover {
  border: 8px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00)
}
```

```html
<div class="figure" style="background-image:url(images/image)">
  <div class="circulo"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que el selector `.circulo:hover` es menos específico que `.figure:hover .circulo` y prevalece este último.

Si cambias el selector por `.figure .circulo:hover` te funcionará perfectamente.

En el siguiente ejemplo he añadido un color de fondo a `.figure` para que se vea más claro el efecto:

```css
.figure {
  position: relative;
  width: 15.1%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  left: 3.9%;
  right: 3.9%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 11% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: #333333;
}

.circulo {
  position: absolute;
  width: 70%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 140px;
  max-width: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  border: solid 8px transparent;
}

.figure:hover .circulo {
  border: 8px solid rgba(225, 225, 225, 0.6);
}

.figure .circulo:hover {
  border: 8px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00)
}
```

```html
<div class="figure" style="background-image:url(images/image)">
  <div class="circulo"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1, a modo de referencia, leer [MDN - CSS > Especificidad](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Especificidad)

Comment: muchas gracias me salvaste :V